# Normalizing Data Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, min

I have multiple arrays of size 262144, and I am trying to use the following code to set all the values of each array to between 0 and 1, inclusive. To be clear, each array will be normalized differently because each has different values.

```
var i;
var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]>max) {
        max = array[i];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i]<min) {
        min = array[i];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var norm = (array[i]-min)/(max-min);
    array[i] = norm;
}
```

However, I know that it's not doing this correctly because when I do the following code, the numbers logged to the console are often  above 1.

```
max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]>max) {
        max = array[i];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]<min) {
        min = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(max);
console.log(min);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: array[i] should be able to be greater than MIN_VALUE and less than MAX_VALUE, right? Am I misunderstanding something? @SterlingArcher

Comment: @gcampbell that was intentional. Is that a problem?

Comment: @user6645395 No, it's not a problem. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @user6645395 no my eyes just played tricks on me. You're right!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me. The following example results in the following normalized array:

```
[
  0,
  0.821917808219178,
  0.0684931506849315,
  0.3835616438356164,
  1
]
```

**Note that `min` and `max` do not have to be between `0` and `1` since they represent the minimal and maximal value of your original array**.

```js
var array = [4, 64, 9, 32, 77];

var i;
var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   if(array[i]>max)
   {
       max = array[i];
   }
}

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   if(array[i]<min)
   {
       min = array[i];
   }
}

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   var norm = (array[i]-min)/(max-min);
   array[i] = norm;
}

max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]>max) {
        max = array[i];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]<min) {
        min = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(array);

console.log(max); // 1
console.log(min); // 0
```

**Edit:**
As you can see in the example, the `min` and `max` value after the normalization should be `0` and `1`, which is the case.

Comment: Why would min and max contain the values for my original array? For the second block of code which I posted, don't min and max get reset to the min and max of the new array? Thank you for you response.

Comment: Also, when I log the full array to the console, I get values above 1.

Comment: As far as I can see, in the second snippet you do not do any normalization at all, you only determine the min/max value of the array. Could you please elaborate your thought process?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain what I meant. I meant that in the first two loops, I find the min and max of the original array, and in the third, I normalize the data. In the last two, I reset max and min to what should hopefully be 0 and 1, because I set them based on the normalized array. I was stating why I disagree with the following statement: "Note that min and max do not have to be between 0 and 1 since they represent the minimal and maximal value of your original array."

Comment: See my edit. Determining the `min` and `max` after the normalization seems to work fine as well. What values are you getting, if not `0` and `1`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38721602/6645395) answer! It's simply that the numbers were being compared as I had not converted them from strings to floats.