# Javascript comparing numbers isn't working

Tags: javascript, floating-point, max

I am trying to [normalize data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705953/normalizing-data-using-javascript/38706216) and realized that it's not working because I am getting the incorrect maximum. However, the comparing of numbers isn't working correctly. Here is my code:

```
var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{ 
    if(array[i]>max)
    {
        max = array[i];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{ 
    if(array[i]<min)
    {
        min = array[i];
    }
}

console.log("max: " + max);
console.log("min: " + min);

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if(array[i]!=0)
    {   
            if(array[i]>max)
            {
               console.log(i+": " + array[i] + " yes");
            }
            else
            {
               console.log(i+": " + array[i] + " no " + max);
            }

    }
}
```

I am getting a lot of console output, but here is one example:

```
241590: 17.5799 no 9.86874
```

meaning that for some reason, JS thinks that 17.5799 is not bigger than 9.86874. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? Thank you!

EDIT 1: When printing array[i] - max, I end up with the correct difference...except it's negative.

Comment: (Note: it's better to use `for (var i = 0` instead of `for (i = 0`.)

Comment: what is the contents of array?

Comment: You can also get max/min with `Math.min.apply(null, array)`. See http://jsbin.com/somexiwopo/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you'r array contains strings, not numbers.

so '9.95799' > '89.86874' => true :)
Use numbers instead

Comment: `parseFloat()` it is, yes

Answer (score 0):

@Darkves is correct - you are seeing this behavior because the array contains string instead of numbers. You should therefore parse the individual items of the array with `parseFloat` and then compare the resulting values.
Here is a code snippet for that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if(parseFloat(array[i])!=0)
    {   
            if(parseFloat(array[i])>max)
            {
               console.log(i+": " + array[i] + " yes");
            }
            else
            {
               console.log(i+": " + array[i] + " no " + max);
            }
    }
}
```

I hope this sheds some more light.